# how to incorporate whats app in my app

Tags: android, whatsapp

I would like to incorporate whats app in my app. my idea is once the user click the whats app logo it automatically open the whats app for the particular contact number i mentioned in my code. I tried few lines of code to achieve this.

**whats app logo to click**

```
whatsapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String cont="7290779900";
            openWhatsappContact(cont);
        }
```

});

**Whats app method**

```
void openWhatsappContact(String number) {


        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));

}
```

This method send SMS to the particular number to download the whats app. but i don't want to send SMS.

The method should directly open the whats app for the particular number. User does not know the contact number mention in whats app method as long as it open the whats app.This code work properly only if we have the contact number already added in our whats app contacts. but the user does not know the contact number mentioned here.

pls help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you missed sms_body in your code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);  
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
startActivity(i);
```